# Front audio jack not working(Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: audio-jack

I have tried alsamixer according to some suggestions but that not working, may be I am wrong in doing some steps to enable it. Please guide me

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to install pavucontrol?

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

And, open it (pavucontrol) -> go to the Configuration tab -> make sure nothing is Muted, or that it is correct Input/Output devices

Edit: If you already have pavucontrol installed, and it's still not working:

- (**If you already had it installed**) Try to remove it, reboot, and install it again. (Some tweaking with pavucontrol is probably needed, in the Input/Output tabs)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have not tried it but I am trying it if it helps I will upvote you.

Comment: Oh,  okay Hope it works; If not,  I will try to figure something out, because this seems to be a problem I had before, a while ago..

Comment: I have installed pavucontrol and it worked, but whenever I switch my computer again I have to reconfigure in I/O devices and choose analog output to make it work. Please provide me a fixed solution for it.